# Making a deck of cards in functions

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function that makes a deck of cards.

I have to define what a card is with the suit and the face using struct and then apply the struct to the function that makes a deck of cards.
It has to print out the deck like this:

```
1H, 2C, 3D, 4S,... // the letters being for spades, hearts, etc.
```

This is my code so far:

```
enum Value{
C, D, H, S
};

enum Suit{
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, J, Q, K, A
};

struct card {
Value val;
Suit suit;
};

void originalDeck (struct card cards[]){

char deck[DeckSize][SuitSize];
for (int i = 0; i < DeckSize ; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SuitSize; ++j) {

    }
}

}
```

I'm having problems with the for loops that assign the faces to the values of the cards. I either get infinity loops or it just prints 1 card.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Your suit and Value enums are backwards ....

Comment: Shouldn't the deck be an array of "struct card"s and not an array of char?  Also what do you do inside the nested loop?

Comment: "I'm having problems with the for loops that assign the faces to the values of the cards" - because the loops don't contain any code.

Comment: The last sentence in this question is not true, because the `Suit` enum (which should be the `Value` enum) has absolutely no chance of compiling. If you need help, please post your real code, see [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

After the second **for** statement add:

```
    printf("%1c%c ",card.suit,card.val);
```

You also need to assign DeckSize and SuitSize, best done with define statements, since they are constants:

```
    #define DeckSize 4
    #define SuitSize 13
```

Answer (score 0):

i would make the deck an array of ints

```
0 = ace of clubs
1 = 2 of clubs
...
50 = Queen of spades
51 = King of spades
```

to display a card

```
   char suit = "CDHS"[card % 13]
   char value="A23456789TJQK"[card%4]
```